# Having issue with compiling mediapipe?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I have py 3.9 and the latest version of PyPI(pip) installed.
I installed mediapipe 3.8(lastest) using: pip install mediapipe
I installed OpenCV + VC tools + setuptools + pyinstaller and all the other needed dependencies...
I coded a simple python script that detects the hands and controls the pc cursor via webcam and it is working perfectly!

However, when I tried to compile it to exe using pyinstaller it has broken. (As I figured out that the problem is that mediapipe thing hasn't been converted to dlls or something like that)...

Is there any solution?

[image]